# How to access multiple models in a single contoller, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

Here is my index method, which is trying to access 2 different Models i.e., Session & Email:

```
def index
    user_session = Session.find_by_user_id(user_id)

if !user_session.blank?
  if setting_orig = GlobalSetting.find_by_settings_session_id(user_session.id)
      @setting = setting_orig.dup
  end

else
  @setting = GlobalSetting.first.dup
end
```

end

But, when I try to create this form:

```
<%= form_for(@setting) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :username %>
 <%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

i am shown this error, undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class. How to make it work, any suggestion ?

Comment: Look at the line numbers in the stack trace to find out where in your code the error came from. Looks like @setting is probably nil, since form_for has to inspect it to find out the model_name.

Comment: I think it gets confused because we are accessing 2 models, the moment I comment user_session = Session.find_by_user_id(user_id) this line, it works alright

Answer (score 2):

Unixmonkey has the right idea, look at your stack trace and figure out where the error is coming from.

Also, you have a hole in your statement logic. If the user_session isn't blank (SOMEONE is logged in) but you can't find an email with setting_session_id equal to user_session.id (user doesn't have an email perhaps?) then @setting never gets declared, thus you will run into your error.

```
def index
  user_session = Session.find_by_user_id(user_id)

  if !user_session.blank? AND setting_orig = GlobalSetting.find_by_settings_session_id(user_session.id)
    @setting = setting_orig.dup
  else
    @setting = GlobalSetting.first.dup
  end 
end
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not EMail, it should be GlobalSetting, wherein the first row is default setting and rest of the rows are users custom settings.

Comment: and remember, this works: user_session = nil #user_session = Session.find_by_user_id(user_id)

Comment: Right, I was just going off your code. Even if it's `GlobalSetting` instead of `EMail` the problem still applies, there's a hole in your logic where `@setting` never gets declared. 

To prove to yourself that @setting not getting declared is the problem, try commenting out all the if statements and just leave `@setting = GlobalSetting.first.dup`. If your code doesn't work with that, then there are other problems